# Return CSV of Chrome Browsing History with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, csv, datetime

What is wrong with my join/left join query that returns an empty column?

The issue I am having is the Datetime fields are returning null/blank.
I am posting my whole process but it seems to only be the query that is not working. The datetime conversions work in this query but not the one below:

```
SELECT datetime(last_visit_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime'), url,title, visit_count, typed_count FROM urls ORDER BY last_visit_time DESC;
```

but it is not the exact data I want.
The ultimate goal is to get every date and time I access every website, and how many times a day. I will send this csv to another system via api.

Here is my process in terminal (MAC) (commandline):
Navigate to the History Folder

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/")
```

then

```
sqlite3 History
```

then at the sqlite prompts "sqlite>"

```
.headers on
.mode csv
.output my.csv
SELECT urls.id, urls.url, urls.title, urls.visit_count, urls.typed_count, datetime((urls.last_visit_time/1000000)-11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'local time'), urls.hidden, urls.favicon_id, datetime((visits.visit_time/1000000)-11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'local time'), visits.from_visit, visits.visit_duration, visits.transition, visit_source.source FROM urls JOIN visits ON urls.id = visits.url LEFT JOIN visit_source ON visits.id = visit_source.id ORDER BY visits.visit_time desc;
```

this is what is returned as csv text: (Note the empty datetime fields)

```
url,    title,  visit_count,    typed_count,    datetime((urls.last_visit_time/1000000)-11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'local time'),    hidden, favicon_id, datetime((visits.visit_time/1000000)-11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'local time'),   from_visit, visit_duration, transition, source
https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html,    Command Line Shell For SQLite,  2,  0,  ,   0,  0,  ,   136309, 0,  1610612736  ,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working query:

```
datetime(      visit_time/1000000 -11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

Not working query:

```
datetime((urls.visit_time/1000000)-11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'local time')
```

You have to spell `localtime` correctly.

Comment: Great spotting. I couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

interim Answer: to my ultimate goal, but not to the issue.
The issue of why I have blank columns is unknown at this point:

Ultimate goal to gather all urls visited:
There is not much point querying all of the fields I was querying. So I simplified the query to just get the urls:

```
select datetime((visits.visit_time/1000000)-11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS VisitTime, urls.url, visits.visit_duration FROM visits LEFT JOIN urls ON visits.url = urls.id order by visits.visit_time
```

urls.visit_count not required because each row is a single count so it was redundant to me.

As a Note it looks like visit.visit_duration only records a duration if you close the tab, if the browser is closed it records 0.

Comment: btw: visit_duration is in micro seconds not milli seconds